# modifying CABasicAnimation's setvalue in runtime?

Tags: iphone, caanimation

I use CABasicAnimation in my project. I used repeatcount.but i want to change the tovalue  whenever count is increased .any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the `toValue` whenever the animation goes through one cycle, you should leave the `repeatCount` at 1 and use the `animationDidStop:finished:` to create a new animation with the changed `toValue`, and so on.